# Can't set href with .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Edit:** It was a Firefox-only problem related to the addon Adblock Plus. Reinstalling the addon put an end to this weird behavior on which URLs with some specific special characters would make anchors disappear altogether.

How do I attribute URLs with specials characters to a href using jQuery?

What I'm doing right now is:

```
var x = encodeURI(myURLhere)
```

Which I know generates valid links, because I've been using `console.log(x)` to check it.

But when I do:

```
$("#tweet").attr("href", x);
```

My anchor simply disappears.

One example of an URL on which that happens:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=%22If%20it%20is%20not%20right%20do%20not%20do%20it;%20if%20it%20is%20not%20true%20do%20not%20say%20it.%22%20%E2%80%93%20Marcus%20Aurelius
```

Does anyone have any suggestion as of what I can do to attribute such URL to my anchor's href?

Comment: Can you create SO Snippet with your issue? Setting `href` to random element should not remove it. Also *disappears* means you can't see link or it is removed from DOM?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle or snippet in your question ?

Comment: Can u show the whole code ?

Comment: it gets disappear because response is getting failed.... check console you may have error `Refused to display....`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because of the `;` character in the string, which is not encoded when using `encodeURI`, instead you need to split the querystring off and just call `encodeURIComponent()` on that directly.

Note: For this snippet to work you will need to open the 'Tweet' link in a new tab, as Twitter cannot be shown within the iframe.

```js
var text = 'If it is not right do not do it; if it is not true do not say it." – Marcus Aurelius"'
var x = encodeURIComponent(text);
$("#tweet").attr("href", 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" id="tweet">Tweet</a>
```

Comment: I never face this issue. got something new. +1

Comment: Your answer does fix the ";" problem, I appreciate it but it's not really what I meant to ask. From what I've noticed, it seems only to happen on Firefox, you can check it here: https://codepen.io/telmo_trooper/pen/VWoZGJ

Comment: On Firefox, if you comment the line `$("#tweet").attr("href", tweetLink);`, the "Tweet it" button simply vanishes. It does not happen on Chromium though.

Comment: I can't help with that, I'm afraid, as I cannot reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Update: I restarted Firefox on safe mode (no addons) and the problem doesn't happen anymore. Which can only mean one of my addons is causing this weird behavior. I'll accept your answer since it illustrates the best way to deal with encoded URLs.

Comment: Next time, you might want to mention "it only happens in Firefox" in the question.

Comment: Update #2: It is Adblock Plus that is making the anchor disappear when the URL has special characters in it. I guess I'll try to overwrite this weird behavior.

Comment: @freedomn-m You're absolutely right, thing is I hadn't noticed when I wrote the question. I assumed I had done something wrong.